# Run $COMPILE object code without saving it to a global first

Tags: intersystems-cache

Caché provides the [`$COMPILE`](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RCOS_fcompile) function to convert an array of of source code strings into object code. The `object` parameter allows you to save the binary object data into a local array variable without affecting any global arrays.

The documentation explains that you can replace the data in `^rOBJ(routine)` for the routine with the lines returned in the `object` parameter and that will change the program that runs for `routine`.

My question is, can I run the `object` array directly without modifying any globals (e.g. saving the lines in `^rOBJ` first)? My code strings are generated dynamically by external applications and cannot be pre-loaded into routines.

I want to limit the access the calling program has to the overall system. Having access to modify `^rOBJ` means being able to change application routines that control the system. It also means that I would have to maintain a bunch of temporary routines, making sure that they get cleaned up in an external process even if the job terminates unexpectedly.

Currently, I am using `XECUTE` to just run the code lines directly, but I would rather use compiled code as it is faster.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a way to run `$COMPILE` code directly. I did find a workaround though:

From `XECUTE` you can `ZLOAD` a common, empty template routine and then `ZINSERT` your code to be compiled but not `ZSAVE` so the changes stay private to the current process. It is then possible to `DO` into the local "routine buffer" version of the routine (apparently compiled and everything) that you inserted just now and run the uploaded code.

From my testing, I found that if I return from the `XECUTE`, `$ZNAME` reverts to the calling routine and the changes uploaded in `ZINSERT` are reverted. Therefore, it is important to do the `ZLOAD`, `ZINSERT` and `DO` all in the same `XECUTE` line.